# DataTables Reload

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

Well, I'm trying to do something for the job, where I need a Table made with the DataTables library to be constantly updating, for example, every 10 seconds.

I'm facing very boring problems, what I'm trying to do is give a Reload on API, as described on the official website **here**: https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()

I'm using this:

```
    function AutoReload1()
    {
        var table = $('#OperationFix').DataTable({
            ajax: "data.json"
        });

        setInterval(function () {
            table.ajax.reload();
        }, 5000);

        //loadOrdersFix();
        //alert('Testing')

    }
```

Then it returns the following error to me:

> DataTables warning: table id=OperationFix - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

Comment: Is the any particular reason this question is tagged C?

Comment: Although it's done in javascript I'm currently doing the application in MVC I thought it would be an important detail to add, if I'm wrong I'm sorry

Comment: So.... did you visit that URL and read the documentation for the error? Seems pretty extensive and well-written.

Comment: Yes, the extension of it is related to solutions, but I tried and nothing, the error itself according to the documentation if it is due to the fact that it is not possible to make the call the table + of 1 time, it can only be initiated 1x

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be fine.

But error which you mentioned occurs when `AutoReload1();` is called again somehow after its already loaded.

To resolve that you need to either add `destroy: true` or find out why `AutoReload1()` is called multiple times.

```
function AutoReload1()
{
    var table = $('#OperationFix').DataTable({
        ajax: "data.json",
        destroy: true
    });

    setInterval(function () {
        table.ajax.reload();
    }, 5000);

}
```

Working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0suj9g31/1/)

**Edit 1:**

As per your fiddle, you have defined Datatable 2 places so add `destroy:true` on both place

```
 var table = $(OperationFixTableId).DataTable({
       dom: 'Bfrtip',
       pageLength: 1000,
       columns: columns,
       data: OperationFix,
       destroy: true
```

Comment: Hello Fiddle, well I tested what "destroy:true" said and it worked out the error changed now only shows that he can n load the table with the result that was brought to me, this because when you use "destroy:true" he loses the parameters that in my case would be a start date and an end date. I would like to know if you know what to do and if you can help me

Comment: I've had this annoying error for a while now, and from what it shows on the official website it seems to be very easy to solve, just select the existing table, talk with which file to load and give a reload. This project is for my work so it's professional use and it matters a lot to me, thanks in advance :)

Comment: In order to get help you need to provide actual code which is causing the issue.  I don't see any start date, end date in your question. Please create a sample Fiddle and share link https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: It's ok, it's hard for me because the code is really big and the company's, today I'm not there anymore, on Thursday I'm in charge.

Comment: To help find out why `AutoReload1() ` is being called multiple times you could try putting `console.trace('optional message here')` inside the function. This will give you a list of the functions called leading up to that point.

Comment: Good morning everyone, thank you for your help so far, I never used JsFiddle, it's the first time. I put all the code from the page where I am trying to autoload the Table, but in the fiddle link I can not see the final result because it is without css, but with the source code html/Js I hope to get help from you, thank you in advance. Link: (https://jsfiddle.net/Apocryphoon/mn9o7rpa/7/)

Comment: But with some changes in the code the error it returns me now is that there is no 'reload' parameter, so far so good since in 'var OperationFixTableId' I did not put .DataTable, when I put it returns me the error 'Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined'

Comment: I was able to fix this error, but now I'm faced with the v7 error that would be ( Not Found ) that Time wanted to try to reload the Table but qnd makes the search ajax he does not return the correct one 

Print: ( http://www.hostcgs.com.br/hostimagem/view.php?filename=124erro_reload_v7.png )

Comment: Here code for error v7: ( https://jsfiddle.net/Apocryphoon/mn9o7rpa/9/ )

Comment: your js is too big to see. try my edit ..  might help

Comment: MyTwoCents Yes, I'm sorry. I'm gonna send what's important here, okay?

Comment: MyTwoCents, I tried to do your Edit1 and it comes back to me, I really didn't understand which one of the colums field : http://www.hostcgs.com.br/hostimagem/view.php?filename=323erro_colums.png

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
    <div class="container">
        <table id="OperationFix" class="display" width="100%">
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th style="text-align:right"></th>
                    <th style="text-align:right"></th>
                    <th style="text-align:right"></th>
                    <th style="text-align:right"></th>
                    <th style="text-align:right"></th>
                    <th style="text-align:right"></th>
                    <th style="text-align:right"></th>
                    <th style="text-align:right"></th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
   var OperationFixTableId = $('#OperationFix');  

    var refreshIntervalId = setInterval;

    function AutoReload1()
    {              

        var OperationFixTableId = $('#OperationFix').DataTable({
            ajax: 'data.json',
            destroy: true
        });

        setInterval(function () {
            OperationFixTableId.ajax.reload();
        }, 5000);

    }


    function AutoReload() {
        var checkbox = document.getElementById('myonoffswitch');


        if (checkbox.checked == true)
        {
            AutoReload1();
        }

        if (checkbox.checked == false)
        {
            clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
        }
    }
```

I'm currently trying to do this, but when I test it I see that he tries to load my DataTable with 'data.json' what I'd like him to do is load it with what he has in the bank as I could do this, my connection is here:

function GetOrdersFix(startDate, endDate, status, type, onSuccess, onError) {
    var uri = executionContext.settings.GetOrdersFix;

```
var data = {
    startDate: new Date(startDate).toJSON(),
    endDate: new Date(endDate).toJSON()
};

if (status) { data.status = status; }

if (type) { data.type = type; }



console.info('Loading orders fix from ' + uri);

//Call to server API
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: uri,
    data: data,
    success: function (responseData, status, jqXHR) {
        onSuccess(responseData);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, status, errorThrown) {
        onError(status + ',' + errorThrown + ',' + jqXHR.responseText);
    }
});
```

}